# DELETE https://{endpoint}/{bucketName} avoid comment Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a basic question in Javascript :

I need to insert this code

```
DELETE https://{endpoint}/{bucketName}
```

And the // comment my line.

How can I avoid it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Insert it _where_, into _what_? Please go read [ask], and then edit your question.

Comment: `{endpoint}` & `{bucketName}` is just placeholder. If you need use it you just need to do `https://someabc.com/S3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line isn't JavaScript. It would error after `DELETE` even before it reaches the `//`.

> ```
> DELETE https://{endpoint}/{bucketName}
>        ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> ```

If you were to use *any* library to make an HTTP request, it would expect the URL to be passed as a string. The sequence `//` has no special meaning *inside a string literal*.

```
xhr.open("DELETE", "https://{endpoint}/{bucketName}");
```